# Triggering a drum module from recorded tracks

Tags: mixing, recording

I want to use my recorded acustic drum tracks to trigger a drum module. How can I do this, and what is the best (inexpensive) drum module to use?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am only familiar with using a VST plugin to trigger MIDI Drum Channels if that helps.

Comment: What makes one drum module better than another, to you?  Both my old Roland TR-626 and Elektron Machindrum are great values *for what they do*, and the thing that each does has a particular use.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you will need to do is translate those acoustic tracks to midi. If they are seperate tracks (kick, snare etc on an audio track each) than you could look at drumagog, a plugin available for most sequencers. If you are in logic on a mac you con do a drum replace that will generate you midi notes that you can send via an audio interface to any drum module of your choice. As far as im aware most modern sequencers (cubase, pro tools etc) will have some form of drum replacement option that will translate those hits to midi.